# Add the possibility to select the city code

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, weather

i want to choose city by selectbox added to this script:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var example = $("#example").flatWeatherPlugin({
          location: "london", //city and region *required   
        });

    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoy6npkj/)

Comment: Given up, sorry. :( Couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the plugin is proprietary, you should ask the developer how to update the location. Probably there is a function which make the changes and then you can fetch the new data.

It's always possible to remove the container which hold the plugin and append it on location change, but it's not so called "a good practice".

Here is a working demo, but still speak with the developer, there should be a way to make it without removing the HTML elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 var example = $("#example").flatWeatherPlugin({
  location: "london", //city and region *required  
 });
 $('#list').on('change', function(){
            var location = $(this).val();
            //remove the previous instance of the element holding the weather plugin
            $("#example").remove();
            //Recreate the element and append it to the holder
            $("#holder").append('<div id="example"></div>');
            $("#example").flatWeatherPlugin({
                location: location, //city and region *required  
            });
            $("#example").flatWeatherPlugin('fetchWeather');
 });
});
```

```css
   /* style the container however you please */
   #example {
    color:#fff; 
    background: #e74c3c;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 270px;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }

   /* styling for this page only, ignore */
   body {background: #95a5a6; font-family: b yekan,sans-serif; background: #ecf0f1; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.evanstoneworks.com/scripts/flatWeatherPlugin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.evanstoneworks.com/scripts/jquery.flatWeatherPlugin.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
    <div id="example"></div>
</div>
<select id="list">
    <option value="london">london</option>
    <option value="tokyo">tokyo</option>
    <option value="paris">paris</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps